# How to check if the field is passed validation?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use jquery validate plugin to verify what user input into the field.
At the same time, I capture `focusout` event and action there:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focusout(function() {
...
});
```

But I don't want to do this action when validation is not passed. How to check it there?

Comment: I suppose that you would need to write a conditional beforehand to check if it did in fact pass the validation test. Do you have code for the validation you are running as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use the valid method

```
if($("#inputField").valid()){
 //do something
}
```

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work properly with non-mandatory fields (`required: false`) - when empty value is there, it returns `false`.